# Dropdown navigation li width not 100% in IE7

Tags: css, sharepoint, navigation, width, html-lists

I'm creating a site in Sharepoint and have a problem with the dropdown navigation... in IE7 the li width is not setting to 100% and honestly it looks pretty stupid.

Having tried (and failed) miserably to get a working example on [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/blizeH/EcaNY/) (unfortunately the live site needs a login, so I can't post a direct link) it's really hard to get an idea of what's going on... but I was kinda hoping this was a fairly common problem (although after a silly amount of time on Google, I've not found a solution) that someone can help with. Apologies again for the very simple and elegant code generated by Sharepoint ;)

Thank you!

[(CSS) Sharepoint's default stylesheet](http://comint.glos.nhs.uk/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css)

[(CSS) my own custom stylesheet](http://comint.glos.nhs.uk/jsna/jsna/jsna/css/jsna.css)

[Firefox vs IE7 comparison shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsmiB.png)

Comment: That's a great shout thanks, but unfortunately I only have Firefox and IE8 at work - and it looks fine on both! I shall grab a screenshot in about 10 hours when I get home... sorry :(

Comment: Have updated with an image of the final navigation in Firefox, it basically looks the same as that, but each item is only as long as the text... if that makes sense?

Comment: You should make a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) demo. Copy the entire HTML for the afflicted page. Copy all CSS into a `<style></style>` element. Make sure that the demo works properly in Firefox - if it does, you can assume that it will be broken in IE7 the same as the real page.

Comment: Many thanks, but as what happened with jsFiddle it really didn't look right, so um... http://comint.glos.nhs.uk/jsna/jsna/Pages/default.aspx (it won't be visible for long btw)

Comment: I cant see problem on that site.. you really need to isolate the problem and make that jsfiddle demo. And btw to your comment above, you know that IE8 can be switched to IE7 mode to test it, right?

Comment: Okay, a quick update - unfortunately I cannot allow access to the site as I do not have the permissions to change the anonymous access in Sharepoint! However I have updated the original post with a direct link to both CSS files, and a **comparison screenshot**. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the li's width which is wrong it's the hyperlink inheriting OOTB styles from coreV4.css

Add this to your custom CSS file.

```
.s4-tn ul.dynamic li a
{
    min-width: auto;
    zoom: normal;
}
```

Tested this on IE 7, 8, 9, FF, Chrome and Safari on a Win7 box.
I don't know what this CSS bug is called but it works :)

Have fun!